# Stop JetBrains IDEs from expanding collapsed code blocks after using 'Find & Replace' feature

Tags: pycharm, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I collapse code blocks before hand, to see an overall picture of everything, before using the "Find & Replace" feature to update a lot of code at one time. It drives me crazy that as soon I hit "Replace All", it expands all the code blocks that included the word I was replacing! Is there anyway to stop it from doing and leave the code I had collapsed as collapsed?

Find & Replace.... code to stay collapsed

Comment: There are keyboard shortcuts/actions for collapsing multiple blocks at once. Does that work for you?

Comment: Found a really old ticket that was declined: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88088 . Then found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177247 -- no activity of any kind for 6 years... Maybe there is a better ticket .. but I could not locate it with my quick search: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BUser%20Interface.%20Find,%20Replace%7D%20expand%20replace

Comment: @LazyOne is right, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177247 is the correct bug report to upvote. No workaround for it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For sure that's the bug.

Please, upvote the issue [IDEA-177247](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177247)